# App Goes Blank and Suspending all threads took: issue

Tags: android

I have a issue with a little android project.
I build a hangman game and when i place a word with repeated letter in the variable called "palavra" the app goes blank.

I believe that the issue is related whit this code piece:

```
while(parciais.contains(Character.toString(letras_possiveis[numero].charAt(0)))){ numero = random.nextInt(26);}
```

I believe in this because when i define this piece like comment, the issue doesn't happen anymore. I searched here and heard something  about place too many comands in the onCreate method and is best to place the code in the method onCreateView(), but i'm studying by myself and i dont know this method yet.
Thank everybody

My MainActivity:

```
package mateus.studio.com.forca;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String palavra = "CAVALO", parciais = "", parciais_botoes = "", letrasacertadas="";
String[] letras_possiveis = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
char[] letras_botoes = new char[25];
String[] letras_certas = new String[palavra.length()];
int erros = 0;

TextView txt_tela, txt_erro;
ImageView imagem;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt_tela = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_palavra);
    txt_erro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_erro);
    imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_status);

    int botoes_letras[] = {R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4,
            R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9,
            R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15,
            R.id.button16,R.id.button17, R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, R.id.button21,
            R.id.button22, R.id.button23, R.id.button24};



  for (int a = 0; a < 25; a++){
        try {
            letras_botoes[a] = palavra.charAt(a);
            parciais = parciais + letras_botoes[a];
        }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Random random = new Random();
            int numero = random.nextInt(26);

            //verifica se a letra gerada pelo random já saiu e só sai do loop quando tem-se uma nova

            while(parciais.contains(Character.toString(letras_possiveis[numero].charAt(0)))){
                numero = random.nextInt(26);
            }
            //Coloca as letras no letras_botões (Mas só depois que formar o nome)

            letras_botoes[a] = letras_possiveis[numero].charAt(0);
            parciais = parciais + letras_botoes[a];
        }
    }

//fOR QUE BUGA CASO TENHA LETRAS IGUAIS
     for (int a = 0; a< 25; a++) {
         Random aleatatorio = new Random();
         int al = aleatatorio.nextInt(25);
         while (parciais_botoes.contains(Character.toString(letras_botoes[al]))) {// Código que buga a parada toda
             al = aleatatorio.nextInt(25);                                         // Código que buga a parada toda
         }

         parciais_botoes = parciais_botoes + letras_botoes[al];

         //aQUI DEVE SE COLOCAR O CODIGO DE INSTANCIAR OS BOTO
         final Button botao;
         botao = (Button) findViewById(botoes_letras[a]);
         botao.setText(Character.toString(letras_botoes[al]));


     }

    for (int a = 0; a < letras_certas.length; a++){
        if (letras_certas[a] == null){
            letras_certas[a]="_ ";
        }
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < palavra.length(); a++){
        txt_tela.setText("_ " + txt_tela.getText());
    }

}



public void verifica_letra(View view) {
    letrasacertadas = txt_tela.getText().toString();
txt_tela.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++) {
        String texto = ((Button) view).getText().toString() ;
        if (palavra.charAt(i) == texto.charAt(0)) {
            letras_certas[i] = texto;

            //  ta de boa, não mexe, pelo amor de Jeová

        } else {
            ((Button) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#800000"));
            }

        verifica_erro(view);
    }

 for (int a = 0 ; a < letras_certas.length ; a++){
     txt_tela.setText(txt_tela.getText() + letras_certas[a]);

 }
}    
   public void verifica_erro (View view){
    if (palavra.contains(((Button) view).getText().toString())) ((Button) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
    else {
        ((Button) view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#800000"));
        erros ++;

    }

   if (letrasacertadas.equals(palavra)){
       setContentView(R.layout.venceu);
   }else {
   switch (erros/palavra.length()){
       case 0:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.base);
           break;

       case 1:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
           break;
       case 2:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
           break;
       case 3:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
           break;

       case 4:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
           break;

       case 5:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);
           break;

       case 6:
           imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.f);
           break;

       default:
           setContentView(R.layout.perdeu);
           break;
   }}

   txt_erro.setText("Erros: "+erros/palavra.length());

}
}
```

This is what i see in Logcat:

```
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? E/Zygote: v2
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10116
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-    G530H_5.0.2-1_0018
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
01-19 22:26:47.815 30117-30117/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-19 22:26:47.905 30117-30117/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
01-19 22:26:47.915 30117-30117/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
01-19 22:26:47.915 30117-30117/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
01-19 22:26:48.135 30117-30117/mateus.studio.com.forca D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
01-19 22:26:48.355 30117-30130/mateus.studio.com.forca I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 247(41KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 62% free, 4MB/12MB, paused 11.957ms total 45.761ms
01-19 22:26:52.035 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.840ms
01-19 22:26:52.545 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30.195ms
01-19 22:26:53.055 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 38.104ms
01-19 22:26:58.055 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 23.713ms
01-19 22:26:58.545 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.573ms
01-19 22:26:59.795 30117-30130/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.640ms
01-19 22:26:59.825 30117-30130/mateus.studio.com.forca I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 176441(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 6.563ms total 48.098ms
01-19 22:27:00.315 30117-30130/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.270ms
01-19 22:27:00.355 30117-30130/mateus.studio.com.forca I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 173108(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 9.271ms total 53.534ms
01-19 22:27:00.545 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.498ms
01-19 22:27:02.585 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 49.126ms
01-19 22:27:03.455 30117-30129/mateus.studio.com.forca I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 34.767ms for cause HeapTrim
01-19 22:27:06.065 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.617ms
01-19 22:27:09.065 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.519ms
01-19 22:27:12.085 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.450ms
01-19 22:27:19.105 30117-30123/mateus.studio.com.forca W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.492ms
01-19 22:27:23.495 30117-30129/mateus.studio.com.forca I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 27.446ms for cause HeapTrim
```

Comment: You're going into garbage collection.  If you're collecting garbage this much you must be creating a ton of objects.  Make sure you aren't overly allocating, especially in critical paths like onDraw or onMeasure.

Comment: Sorry, but i am a newbie and i don't understand too much about code :(
What i can do to solve my problem? Garbage Collection is an unknown topic to me.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Perform a lot fewer allocations and find your leaks.  Garbage collection is a sign you're making serious mistakes in your program, its not an "add this line here and it'll be fixed" problem.